# Pass class as param into function which returns an object of this type in swift?

Tags: swift, class, instantiation, func, function-parameter

I need to write something like this:

```
func createInstanceOfClass(someClass: Class) -> UIViewController {
  var vc = someClass()

  //some initialization
  ...
  //

  return 
}
```

I found some similar questions but some of them are not appropriate for this task, some about param `T` which seems to be extra.

Comment: Your function is returning ViewController. What is that?

Comment: fixed code. Simply in my particular case this method creates and initializes view controllers according to the given view controller's class.

Comment: What you need is a generic function, which is why the answers you found use a `T` parameter. I would suggest reading about generics in Swift and then taking another look at the answers you've found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might do this. Use `T.Type` to reference the metatype of `T`, and `T.self` to reference the type `T`.

```
protocol DefaultConstructible {
    init()
}

class A: DefaultConstructible {
    required init() {}
}

struct B: DefaultConstructible {
    init() {}
}

func makeAnInstance<T: DefaultConstructible>(of c: T.Type) -> T {
    return c.init()
}

let a = makeAnInstance(of: A.self)
let b = makeAnInstance(of: B.self)
```